# How to free memory by pointer a (placement new)?

Tags: c++, delete-operator, placement-new

I can't understand how to properly free the memory by pointer a

```
MemoryManager mm;
char* a = new(mm) char[len];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call the destructor (if needed) and deallocate with your memory manager

```
// Deallocate memory
MemoryManager.free(a);
```

Or, you could define a delete operator for your custom allocator:

```
void operator delete(void *ptr, const MemoryManager &m) {...}
...
operator delete(a, mm);
```